# When Python code outputs an array or list of arrays. are those NumPy array or something else?

Tags: python, numpy

My Python code outputs a list of arrays. My question is;
are those NumPy arrays or something else?

When trying to use those outputs by copying and pasting to new Python code I am getting a type error which I think arise if they are NumPy arrays.

```
import numpy as np

    class Network(object):

        def __init__(self, sizes):
            """The list ``sizes`` contains the number of neurons in the
            respective layers of the network.  """
            self.num_layers = len(sizes)
            self.sizes = sizes
            self.biases = [np.random.randn(y, 1) for y in sizes[1:]]
            self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)
                            for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]

        def feedforward(self, a):
            """Return the output of the network if ``a`` is input."""
            for b, w in zip(self.biases, self.weights):
                a = np.dot(w, a)+b
            return a


    Network = Network([2,3,1])
    print(Network.feedforward([1,5]))
    print(Network.weights)
    print(Network.biases)
    print(type(Network.weights))

here is the output
[[-3.29027694 -2.17332051 -0.55471131]]

[array([[-1.06867352,  1.10685543],
           [-0.03651884,  0.59706138],
           [ 1.35881759, -0.12161689]]), array([[-1.52001116,  
     0.44110627,  0.34252238]])]

[array([[-0.25784339],
           [ 0.50499638],
           [-0.00993926]]), array([[-0.61316203]])]

<class 'list'>
```

Comment: The type clearly shows they are not numpy arrays. A numpy array will have class 'numpy.ndarray'.
To solve the issue you can simply convert the lists to numpy arrays, you can use numpy.asarray(your_list)

Comment: Just FYI. if you want to know the type of an elemnt of the list, just use the `type` function: write `print(type(somelist[0]))` to print the type of the first element of `somelist`.

Comment: so can we drive a conclusion here that initial values of a defined function (like in our case self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)  for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]) and there returned outputs (in our case [array([[-1.06867352,  1.10685543], [-0.03651884,  0.59706138], [ 1.35881759, -0.12161689]]),      array([[-1.52001116,  0.44110627,  0.34252238]])]) can not be used vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the array is shown to be a regular list. If you want to convert this list to a numpy array you can use the [numpy.asarray](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html) function.

Here's some examples of the usage of the asarray function:

```
np.asarray([1,5])

my_tuple = ([1, 3, 9], [8, 2, 6]) 
out_arr = geek.asarray(my_tuple)
```

Source: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-asarray-in-python/

The reverse can also be done using [np.array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html). This will input a regular python list/array and return a numpy array.

Comment: so can we drive a conclusion here that initial values of a defined function (like in our case self.weights = [np.random.randn(y, x)  for x, y in zip(sizes[:-1], sizes[1:])]) and there returned outputs (in our case [array([[-1.06867352,  1.10685543], [-0.03651884,  0.59706138], [ 1.35881759, -0.12161689]]),      array([[-1.52001116,  0.44110627,  0.34252238]])]) can not be used vice versa.  can we conclude that they are equal but not same.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, thanks @gmoshkin to clear the fog around me.

When python code outputs array or list of arrays and you haven't imported array from array and did only numpy imports and operations, code can not out put any array but numpy arrays or lists with elements having numpy arrays only. As we make type of element check by:

print(type(Network.weights[0])), we get output: class 'numpy.ndarray'>
So it is in fact a list of numpy arrays not a list of standard arrays.